# "found to do" versus "found who do"

Tags: sentence-construction

> I’m sorry, the position has been filled (=someone has been found **to** do the job).

> Someone has been found **to** do the job.
> Someone has been found **who would** do the job.
> (I think that the role of "**to**" is the same as that of "**who would**")

I can't understand why "**to** do the job" is not part of the subject.
"**Who would** do the job" is part of the subject.
I think that the role of "**to**" is the same as that of "**who would**", and that "**to** do the job" is also part of the subject.

1. What is the reason "**to** do the job" is not part of the subject even though "**who would** do" is
2. What would you paraphrase "**to**"?

Comment: **to** is part of the infinitive **to do**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your analysis, you consider the clause is "to do the job", and suppose that the subject of this clause is "to", and moreover that "to" is therefore a pronoun referring to "someone".

There are lots of problems with this analysis.  It should be possible to replace a pronoun with its antecedent and get a valid sentence, but this is not correct grammar.

> *Someone has been found someone do the job.

It should be possible to use a different noun phrase for the subject but this  is not correct. The only word you can use here is "to".

So what *is* to?  It isn't a pronoun, and it isn't the subject. Instead, it *marks* the following clause as an infinitive clause. It is an operator, indicating the grammatical structure.  Since the clause "do the job" is a subordinate clause, and "to" marks it as subordinate, you can call "to" a subordinator.

So what is the subject of "do the job".  There is no expressed subject, but there is an understood subject.  English does not permit understood subjects for independent clauses, but it does permit them for subordinate infinitive clauses and caused headed by -ing verbs.  To understand the subject of the clause you use context, and in this context "someone" is understood to be the subject.

Sometimes similar ideas can be expressed in different ways, and this can lead to confusion.  So the pronoun "who" can be the subject in a clause "who would do the job", but this doesn't mean that "to" means "who would"

Comment: Is the "to post personal information" in "Permission has been given to post personal information" not part of the subject?

Comment: No, in that passive sentence the syntactic subject is "Permission".  The subject of a passive sentence has the role that the object would take in an active sentence.   The semantic "agent" is omitted (it could be included with a "by ....")